# How to use else with a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, control-flow

Maybe that's a stupid question and a stupid mistake by me but i can't get this control flow to work.
here is my simplified code:

```
for x in range(1,10):
    print(x)
    if x==2:
        print("working")
        break
else:
    print("stop")
```

here is the result on shell:

```
1
2
working
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: This is doing exactly as it should, if you always want the stop to print remove the else and put the print outside the loop

Comment: Looking at this question the output you got was expected. If you want the `for loop` to print 'Stop', then it needs to have not been `break`'d. The `else` clause in `for loops` is only executed when a `for loop` has been completely run.

Comment: i was expecting the else clause to be executed when the break was used. My Bad, i did not understand the documentation well enough. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is working as expected and specified. From [the official Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for):

> A break statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop
>   without executing the else clause’s suite.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I read the documentation wrong. Answer accepted and upvoted.

Comment: thanks, @elunaery, but I don't see the acceptance just yet :)